# Prove using minimal logic that $\neg\neg\neg A \rightarrow \neg A$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, sequent-calculus

Prove using natural deduction for minimal logic that $\neg\neg\neg A \rightarrow \neg A$.

I'm trying to prove this argument using only the rules of minimal logic.

So far I have this.

$$1. ⊢ \neg\neg\neg A \rightarrow \neg A$$
$$2. \neg\neg\neg A ⊢ \neg A$$
$$3. \neg\neg\neg A, A ⊢ \bot$$
$$4.1 \neg\neg\neg A, A ⊢ A (DONE)$$
$$4.2 \neg\neg\neg A, A ⊢ \neg A $$

And from the branch 4.2 I don't know how to proceed.

Can someone help?

Comment: What is 'minimal logic'? Can you please explain or provide a reference?

Comment: @bram28 “Minimal logic” is a standard term for a specific logical system.  You can find it in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 4):

Until step $3$, your attempt goes in the right direction. Your step $4$ is problematic, because$-$as you noticed$-$in the branch $4.2$ it is not clear what to do. Indeed, your branch $4.2$ is very similar to your step $2$, which roughly means that from step $2$ to step $4$ your attempt did not achieve any progress.

The solution is to remark that your step $3$ (which expresses a contradiction between $\lnot\lnot\lnot A$ and $A$) can be obtained in several ways, not only via your step $4$.
Your step $4$ derives step $3$ by putting together $A$ and $\lnot A$, but my suggestion is to derive step $3$ by putting together $\lnot \lnot \lnot A$ and $\lnot \lnot A$.
The derivation you obtain is below (I draw it as a tree, built bottom up).

\begin{align}
\dfrac{
  \dfrac{
    \dfrac
    {\dfrac{}{\lnot \lnot \lnot A, A \vdash \lnot \lnot \lnot A}\text{ax} \qquad \dfrac{\vdots}{\lnot \lnot \lnot A, A \vdash \lnot \lnot A}}
    {\lnot \lnot \lnot A, A \vdash \bot}
    \lnot_e
  }
  {\lnot \lnot \lnot A \vdash \lnot A}
  \lnot_i
}
{\vdash \lnot \lnot \lnot A \to \lnot A}
\to_i
\end{align}

It remains to find a derivation for $\lnot \lnot \lnot A, A \vdash \lnot \lnot A$ (the vertical dots above), which is quite easy:

\begin{align}
\dfrac{
  \dfrac{\dfrac{}{\lnot \lnot \lnot A, A, \lnot A \vdash \lnot A}\text{ax} \qquad \dfrac{}{\lnot \lnot \lnot A, A, \lnot A \vdash A}\text{ax}}{\lnot \lnot \lnot A, A, \lnot A \vdash \bot}\lnot_e
}
{\lnot \lnot \lnot A, A \vdash \lnot \lnot A}
\lnot_i
\end{align}

We have only used rules that are admissible in minimal logic.

Answer (score 0):

A deduction has been given in the other answer, so here a shorter argument passing through a more general theorem:

1. The proposition $A\to [(A\to B)\to B]$ always holds - it is related to modus ponens
2. If $A\to B_\text{weak}$ holds, then $(B_\text{weak}\to C)\to(A\to C)$ does too - it is a form of transitivity familiar from taking a contrapositive
3. If, in 2., for $B_\text{weak}$ we consider $[(A\to B)\to B]$, then using 1. we get $([(A\to B)\to B]\to C)\to(A\to C)$
4. Considering the special case $C=B$, we can see $([(A\to B)\to B]\to B)\leftrightarrow(A\to B)$
5. Considering the special case $B=\bot$, we get the result $\neg[\neg\neg A]\leftrightarrow\neg A$

If we wish to disprove some claim, say the existence statement $A=\exists x. P(x)$, we can inspect this hypothetical existence and show that it would imply an inconsistency.
But already over minimal logic, it really suffices to inspect the claim that the existence cannot be ruled out.